# Why does glibc have 2 versions of the same functions?

Tags: glibc

I don't fully understand the versioning mechanism of glibc.
In what cases do the developers decide a function needs a new version, and that function is no longer "backward compatible" in glibc and a new GLIBC_2.X version needs to be introduce?

In the case of a function's prototype change, or an API change, I understand, but what more causes are there?

i.e. fnmatch:

I'm looking at a `readelf` output on my glibc 2.19 and I see 2 versions of fnmatch:

```
151: 000bff40   892 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 fnmatch@GLIBC_2.0
152: 000bff40   892 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 fnmatch@@GLIBC_2.2.3
```

But when I look at glibc's code, I see they are exactly the same function:

```
versioned_symbol (libc, __fnmatch, fnmatch, GLIBC_2_2_3);
#  if SHLIB_COMPAT(libc, GLIBC_2_0, GLIBC_2_2_3)
strong_alias (__fnmatch, __fnmatch_old)
compat_symbol (libc, __fnmatch_old, fnmatch, GLIBC_2_0);
#  endif
```

So why do fnmatch even has 2 versions?
What other causes are there for the developers to start a "new version" of a function?

Answer (score 2):

The interface also changes in case of ABI change, e.g. some change in an internal structure that could be visible by code compiled against an old version of the library. This needs new versioned symbols.

By default, when compiling code, the current version is chosen. Old versions are also provided by the glibc to allow one to get binaries (provided by the vendor) compiled with old glibc versions and run them on one's machine (which has a newer glibc version).

Comment: but what change is there between the 2 versions of fnmatch? They're exactly the same function..

Comment: @speller Due to the use of the preprocessor, you do not know whether they are the same function. Actually they are probably different. The log says about `fnmatch.c`: "Define with new default version GLIBC_2.2.3 to avoid running binaries with libc versions without FNM_EXTMATCH support."

Comment: what do you mean by "use of preprocessor"? I've quoted from the source and you can see that fnmatch@GLIBC_2_2_3 and fnmatch@GLIBC_2_0 are exactly the same function

Comment: @speller I suppose that there are several compilations, e.g. one with `SHLIB_COMPAT(libc, GLIBC_2_0, GLIBC_2_2_3)` being true and one with it being false. Otherwise I don't see the need for such a `#if` test. Then this would mean two different versions of the function (because of different preprocessor macros for each compilation). Unfortunately the glibc source doesn't seem to be well-documented concerning the internal mechanisms.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense - all the SHLIB_COMPAT macro do is check if we want to be compatible with the older version of glibc..